# Reset default CSS list counter outside of a list

Tags: css

Suppose I have the following sequence of paragraphs:

```
<p id="par-1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</p>
<p id="par-2">consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
<p id="par-3">Cras est augue,</p>
<p id="par-4">luctus vitae pretium ut,</p>
<p id="par-5">scelerisque nec libero.</p>
<p id="par-6">Phasellus condimentum sollicitudin mi,</p>
<p id="par-7">vitae molestie tellus cursus vitae.</p>
```

If I now style some of the paragraphs to [display as `list-item`s](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display), then their numbering seems to start with the first item and continues on sequentially:

```
#par-2,                                                                                                   
#par-4,
#par-6 {                                                                                                  
  display: list-item;                                                                                   
  list-style-position: inside;                                                                          
  list-style-type: decimal;                                                                             
}
```

renders as

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
1. consectetur adipiscing elit.
Cras est augue,
2. luctus vitae pretium ut,
scelerisque nec libero.
3. Phasellus condimentum sollicitudin mi,
vitae molestie tellus cursus vitae.
```

**Questions**

Is the list counter, the one used here implicitly, accessible to CSS?  Can I [reset that counter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/counter-reset)? Where do I find more information on this? (The [“Generated Content”](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/generate.html) section over at `w3.org` doesn’t share much detail.)

PS: I am not looking for a replacement implementation that imitates the described behavior, I am looking for details to understand and to manipulate the existing one.

Answer (score 1):

There is two ways to do this (if I catch your intentions) :

- Show a regular list like yours, but hide the counter on some with `list-type: none`
- Or create a custom CSS counter and selectively increment it

```css
body {
  /* Initialise the counter on any parent */
  counter-reset: section;
}

p[id^='par-'] {
  /* Increment the counter each time we encounter a p with an id that starts with "par-" */
  counter-increment: section;
}

#par-2::before,
#par-4::before,
#par-6::before {
  /* Insert the counter value before the content */
  content: counter(section) ". ";
}
```

```html
<p id="par-1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</p>
<p id="par-2">consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
<p id="par-3">Cras est augue,</p>
<p id="par-4">luctus vitae pretium ut,</p>
<p id="par-5">scelerisque nec libero.</p>
<p id="par-6">Phasellus condimentum sollicitudin mi,</p>
<p id="par-7">vitae molestie tellus cursus vitae.</p>
```

Comment: So there is no access to whatever internal counter an `<ol>` or `<ul>` element use?

Answer (score 0):

On div you will use any class name instead of class="container". I have checked and it's working.

```css
.container p:before {
  counter-increment: mycounter;
  content: counter(mycounter) ". ";
}

.container:first-of-type {
  counter-reset: mycounter;
}

.container p:nth-child(2n+1):before {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</p>
  <p>consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
  <p>Cras est augue,</p>
  <p>luctus vitae pretium ut,</p>
  <p>scelerisque nec libero.</p>
  <p>Phasellus condimentum sollicitudin mi,</p>
  <p>vitae molestie tellus cursus vitae.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for edit code in snippet. I hope you have found your solutions in my code

Comment: Please send your feedback so other person known your issue is resolved if anyone face same problem.

Comment: I am not looking for an implementation to imitate the described behavior, I am looking to manipulate the existing one.

Answer (score 0):

Best Practice

```css
ol li{list-style-position: inside;}
```

```html
<div class="container"> 
<ol>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</p>                             
<li>consectetur adipiscing elit.</li>                                   
  <p>Cras est augue,</p>                                              
<li>luctus vitae pretium ut,</li>                                
  <p>scelerisque nec libero.</p>                                   
<li>Phasellus condimentum sollicitudin mi,</li>                        
  <p>vitae molestie tellus cursus vitae.</p> 
<ol>
</div>
```

Comment: I am not looking for an implementation to imitate the described behavior, I am looking to manipulate the existing one.

Comment: Nesting `<p>` into a list doesn’t make much sense semantically and messes with [accessibility](https://a11yproject.com/) of the structure, doesn’t it?